# How do I get HTML Tidy to not put newline before closing tags?

Tags: html, text, tidy, text-formatting, htmltidy

HTML Tidy has this infuriating habit of putting a newline **before** the closing tag. For example:

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

becomes

```
<p>Some text
</p>
```

How do I tell Tidy to keep the closing tag on the same line as the end of the content?

Btw, I am running Tidy through Notepad++, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure `vertical-space` is set to `no`. After much frustration I learned the only thing that switch does is screw up your already somewhat-nicely formatted html by adding newlines where you don't want them.

This is what I use for minimally-invasive tidying (no adding doctypes/head tags, etc.):

`tidy -mqi --doctype omit --show-body-only true --show-warnings no --vertical-space no --wrap 0`

Comment: Upvoted, but feel I should add a **warning** to readers: the `-m` option causes `tidy` to **m**odify files in place (i.e. to overwrite them). Omit it unless you have a backup, or are otherwise happy for your existing file(s) to be clobbered.

Answer (score 1):

hmm I don't see it in windows.

I am using Tidy with ruby

```
   @tidy.options.output_xhtml = true
   @tidy.options.show_body_only = true
   @tidy.clean('<p>Some text</p>')
```

I also ran the tidy script in unbuntu (tidy -m test.htm) but did not see that problem.
You can control the spacing using the options at
http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#PrettyPrintHeader

Comment: I've looked at those options before and none of those seem to do the needful. Btw, I am running TIDY through Notepad++, if that makes any difference.

Comment: don't know how to do it with NotePad++ but 
'wrap=160' option might help. But the issue that you are seeing might be related to notePad++

Answer (score -9):

In php you can use:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/\n<\//smUi','</',$buffer);
```