# htmltidy problems about script tags

Tags: htmltidy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get HTML Tidy to not put newline before closing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491657/how-do-i-get-html-tidy-to-not-put-newline-before-closing-tags)

I have used htmltidy for few days, but there is always a "bug" happened when using it. This bug will wrap my script tag automatically !!

I have to mention that they are just inline scripts which only link to the the external scripts.

After searching advanced tidy commands, I still can't solve this weird problem. Has anyone ever met this kind of situation before ?

**My personal configurations**

```
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 4
wrap: 0
tidy-mark: no
char-encoding: utf8
doctype: auto
```

**My non-tidied test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/generic.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**My tidied test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/generic.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```