# PHP Tidy new empty line inside title tag and js tag

Tags: php, tidy

I have a question about tidy.

My problem is like this one [HTML Tidy new empty line after closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843252/html-tidy-new-empty-line-after-closing-tags).

My current setting will not have new empty line for the html inside of body tag and head tag, expect `title tag` and `js tag`.

The output is like below.

```
     <title>
      XXXX
    </title>
     <script src="core.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

My current setting

```
$config = array(
            'doctype' => '<!doctype html>',
            "char-encoding" => "utf8",
            'vertical-space' => false,
            'indent' => true,
            'wrap' => 0,
            'word-2000' => 1,
            'break-before-br' => true,
        );
```

I already added `'vertical-space' => false,` I dont know why and how should I do to solve this problem.

I want them to be

```
         <title> XXXX </title>
         <script src="core.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
```

Thank  you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

try add to options

```
'output-xml' => true
```

Comment: Good answer should provide complete information about solution instead of proposal to try something. You can edit your answer to make it better and more valuable for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $tidy_config = array(
        'indent' => true,
        'wrap' => 0,
        'output-xml' => true);
```