# Tidy adding too many newlines

Tags: html, tidy, htmltidy

I am quite new to tidy, and I am trying to format some HTML files. I have a section that looks like:

```
<table>
    <tr><th class="x">Some stuff:</th><th class="x"><span class="y">{{qwe}}</span></th></tr>
    <tr><th class="x">Some more stuff:</th><th class="x">{{rty}}</th></tr>
    <tr><th class="x">Thing 1 / thing 2 / thing 3:</th><th class="x">{{asd}} / {{fgh}} / {{poi}}</th></tr>
    <tr><th class="x">Some file name:</th><th class="x"><a href="{{lkj}}" target="_blank">{{mnb}}</a></th></tr>
</table>
```

I created this tidy config file:

```
vertical-space: no
wrap: 0
new-blocklevel-tags: section, header
sort-attribute: alpha
```

I ran `tidy -config ~/tidy-config.txt -m myfile.html` on the file and the section above gets formatted like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">Some stuff:</th>

    <th class="x"><span class="y">{{qwe}}</span></th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th class="x">Some more stuff:</th>

    <th class="x">{{rty}}</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th class="x">Thing 1 / thing 2 / thing 3:</th>

    <th class="x">{{asd}} / {{fgh}} / {{poi}}</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th class="x">Some file name:</th>

    <th class="x"><a href="{{lkj}}" target="_blank">{{mnb}}</a></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I like that each `<th>` tag got split on separate lines but I don't like all the extra newlines. Overall, this looks worse than the original to me because it's too sparse! Is there a way to have a more compact pretty print? Or set which tags get a newline after they are closed? I dug through config options but could not find anything useful.

**EDIT:**

I'd like something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">Some stuff:</th>
    <th class="x"><span class="y">{{qwe}}</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">Some more stuff:</th>
    <th class="x">{{rty}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">Thing 1 / thing 2 / thing 3:</th>
    <th class="x">{{asd}} / {{fgh}} / {{poi}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">Some file name:</th>
    <th class="x"><a href="{{lkj}}" target="_blank">{{mnb}}</a></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By all means, if you can suggest a different tool to use, please do.

Comment: don't use HTML tidy c'mon this isn't 1997!

Comment: @LoydChristmas will you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Tables don't typically have more than one row with `th` nodes. Use `td` instead.

Comment: @Jonathan That table happens to use `th` nodes because it doesn't contain data. Using `td` does not change the formatting issue.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29961363/825588

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Tidy new empty line after closing tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843252/html-tidy-new-empty-line-after-closing-tags)

Answer (score 2):

setting `indent` to true

```
indent: true
indent-spaces: 2
vertical-space: no
wrap: 0
new-blocklevel-tags: section, header
sort-attributes: alpha
```

will you give you this output

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">
      Some stuff:
    </th>
    <th class="x">
      <span class="y">{{qwe}}</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">
      Some more stuff:
    </th>
    <th class="x">
      {{rty}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">
      Thing 1 / thing 2 / thing 3:
    </th>
    <th class="x">
      {{asd}} / {{fgh}} / {{poi}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="x">
      Some file name:
    </th>
    <th class="x">
      <a href="{{lkj}}" target="_blank">{{mnb}}</a>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's even worse! :) Modified my question with the desired output.